# Facebook Authentication using PHP-SDK

Tags: php, facebook, oauth

I've been trying for couple days now without luck, I managed to use the example.php that comes with PHP-SDK and worked perfectly. I just need to store the returned session and use it later on so I could access without re-authenticating.

I tried storing the sessions in a serialized field in a database and then, restoring the data, unserializing it and using setSession function in the php-sdk to retrieve the authentication. Unfortunately, that did not work,

Here is a link to a previous question with the code samples..

[Facebook OAuth retrieve information based on stored session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742137/facebook-oauth-retrieve-information-based-on-stored-session)

Please advice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook OAuth retrieve information based on stored session](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3742137/facebook-oauth-retrieve-information-based-on-stored-session)

Answer (score 7):

### **Update:** Offline Access in [now deprecated](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/). Use something else instead.

---

If you want to use the access token of the user even after he has logged out of your app, you have to ask for the `offline_access` permission.

With the Facebook PHP SDK v3 ([see on github](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk)), it is pretty simple. To log someone with the `offline_access` permission, you ask it when your generate the login URL. Here is how you do that.

## Get the offline access token

First you check if the user is logged in or not :

```
require "facebook.php";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => YOUR_APP_ID,
    'secret' => YOUR_APP_SECRET,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $user = null;
  }
}
```

If he is not, you generate the "Login with Facebook" URL asking for the `offline_access` permission :

```
if (!$user) {
    $args['scope'] = 'offline_access';
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($args);
}
```

And then display the link in your template :

```
<?php if (!$user): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $loginUrl ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
<?php endif ?>
```

Then you can retrieve the offline access token and store it. To get it, call :

```
if ($user) {
    $token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
    // store token
}
```

## Use the offline access token

To use the offline access token when the user is not logged in :

```
require "facebook.php";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => YOUR_APP_ID,
    'secret' => YOUR_APP_SECRET,
));

$facebook->setAccessToken("...");
```

And now you can make API calls for this user :

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
```

Hope that helps !

Comment: offline access i deprecated now: https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/#page_access_token