# Facebook login to site bugs

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-php-sdk

When users come to my site they have the option to log in through facebook. If they are logged in to facebook, and hit the fb login button, it will show all the appropriate logged in dialog. However, if you log out of facebook (either through my site or through facebook itself) and then try to log in through my site again, it will bring you to facebook to sign in, then bring you back to my site. The url changes from x.net/index.php to x.net/index.php?state=... bunch of letters / numbers, but then doesn't return logged in dialog. Hit the button once again after that, and the page refreshes with a different (but similar) url, and returns all the logged in dialog.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Here is the code I use to connect to facebook and get the login and logout urls.

```
//facebook application
$fbconfig['appid' ]     = "myAppId";
$fbconfig['secret']     = "myAppSecret";
$fbconfig['baseurl']    = "http://myNeatSite.net/index.php"; 


if (isset($_GET['request_ids'])){
    //user comes from invitation
    //track them if you need
}

$user            =   null; //facebook user uid
try{
    include_once "facebook.php";
}
catch(Exception $o){
    error_log($o);
}
// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $fbconfig['appid'],
  'secret' => $fbconfig['secret'],
  'cookie' => true,
));

//Facebook Authentication part
$user       = $facebook->getUser();


$loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'scope'         => 'email,publish_stream',
            'redirect_uri'  => $fbconfig['baseurl']
        )
);

$logoutUrl  = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();


if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
 $user = null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I see, you only process the case `$user` is not null (which means the user is already logged in), but ignore the other case.

```
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
 $user = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you should go through an example about how to do authentication with FB, which will make you understand more. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3745332/facebook-authentication-using-php-sdk